# Django Annotate

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to annotate by a field within the model and another model object?

I have a `Restaurant` model object that I want to annotate a 'weight' field. My criteria is number of reviews + number of visits. I would like to do something like this:

```
weighted = Restaurant.objects.annotate(
    weight = Count('reviews') + num_visits??).order_by('weight')
```

The num_visits part is giving an error and I'm not sure how to correct this. `num_visits` is a field in the `Restaurant` model. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need something like this

```
qs = Restaurant.objects.annotate(weight=Count('reviews') + F('num_visits'))
weighted = qs.order_by('weight')
```

It's making use of an [`F` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

Comment: This worked perfectly! For those who are wondering, the imports are: `from django.db.models import Count` and `from django.db.models import F`